# Furnace only blows 55 degree air! Pipes freezing, please help

Tags: furnace

My brother's cabin has a heil horizontal mount attic furnace model # NTC 5100 BFE2 that runs on propane. It's about 14 years old. Only 3 of the 4 burners work, but the heat only comes out at 55 degrees. The heat on the exhaust stack outside in 10 degree weather is 98. The main blower clicks on simultaneously,  and the induced motor squeals,  and on one start up, not at all, with flames coming out against the shield. I'm sure it has multiple issues, but looking for options. The flame was originally orange, but now at least is over 50 percent blue. I'm at a loss as to where all the heat is going.

Thank you!

Comment: Not clear from your message whether you know, but in case you don't know: **blue is good, orange is bad** for a gas furnace flame. Blue indicates full combustion, yellow or orange indicates incomplete combustion == less efficient & more carbon monoxide.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an HVAC service company that works on propane appliances look at, clean and service this unit before it hurts someone. Everything you describe is an accident "waiting to happen". Do not be a victim.